# Software Transaction Memory in Haskell: Couldn't match expected type STM a0 with actual type IO ()

Tags: haskell, stm

I have a small program that defines an account, a withdraw function and attempts to withdraw from it. However, it doesn't compile due and throws the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘(STM a0 -> IO a0)
                                    -> STM () -> IO ()’
                  with actual type ‘IO ()’
```

It seems like the compiler doesn't recognise the conversion from STM to IO. Any pointers would be great.

```
import System.IO
import Control.Concurrent.STM

type Account = TVar Int

withdraw :: Account -> Int -> STM ()
withdraw acc amount = do
    bal <- readTVar acc    
    writeTVar acc (bal - amount)

good :: Account -> IO ()
good acc = do
    hPutStr stdout "Withdrawing..."
    {-hi-}atomically{-/hi-} (withdraw acc 10)

main = do
    acc <- atomically (newTVar 200)
    good acc 
    hPutStr stdout "\nDone!\n"
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? (right now it is a bit hard to find out where the error is located)

Comment: It looks that, due to your `{-hi-}`s, etc. you inlined the `atomically`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{-hi-}` and `{-/hi-}` comment result in "indenting" the `automically`, so as a result, you wrote `hPutStr stdout "Withdrawing..." atomically (withdraw acc 10)`. For example if you write:

```
good :: Account -> IO ()
good acc = do
        hPutStr stdout "Withdrawing..."
 {-hi-} atomically (withdraw acc 10)
```

it works fine, since the "noise" (the `{-hi-}` comment) does not result in inlining the `atomically` function.

The comment indeed has no effect semantically, but you can consider it replaced by whitespace.

Comment: Wow. I never realized that comments can interfere with indentation, mostly because it's quite uncommon to see a comment before code on the same line.